# Mocha's regexp_matches missing some times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hudson, autotest, mocha.js

I'm having a hard time getting any consistant behavior from Mocha and the [regexp_matches](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/ParameterMatchers.html#M000026) method.  If autotest runs my entire test suite everything works fine.  If I purposely cause the test containing the `regexp_matches` call to fail and then fix it I get a `method_missing` error on `regexp_matches`.  If I then run the entire test suite again, everything is fine.  The bigger problem is coming from [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) (continuous integration).  It runs the entire test suite but always says `regexp_matches` is missing and I don't know how to fix it.

My test:

```
test "if token is set during Account creation the long url should be created correctly" do
  Account.any_instance.expects(:http_get).with("api.server.com", regexp_matches(%r(^http://.*/accounts/\d+/jobs$)))
  account = Account.create name: "New Account", token: "NewToken"
end
```

The error:

```
test_if_token_is_set_during_Account_creation_the_long_url_should_be_created_correctly(AccountTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `regexp_matches' for #<AccountTest:0x0000010162d0c0>
    test/unit/account_test.rb:158:in `block in <class:AccountTest>'
```

I don't even know what other code to add here as I can't imagine what the cause is.  For giggles I pasted `require 'mocha'` at the top of the test file but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on a rails project when removing

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

I did this so that running the spec would not load the whole rails environment. This means that external dependencies have to be required or mocked. Mocha obviously needs to be required.

But even after specifying

```
require 'mocha'
```

I ran into the same method missing issue.

Ultimately, I solved it by including the parameter matchers module directly:

```
require_relative "../../../lib/some_class"
require "mocha"

include Mocha::ParameterMatchers

describe SomeClass do
  it "should do things" do
  ...
```